# Connect socket io and node js to remote website

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Guys I want a very small example that uses **node.js and socket.io** that is hosted on `c9.io` or any server that can host **node.js and socket.io** and this website can connect to a client website that is host on shared hosting in another hosting company.

I am trying to create **live chat customer servers** which will connect between chat application created using **node.js and socket.io** and this chat will have its second part on the client side which is the customers website by implementing small html and js code on them website.

Comment: yea I saw it but it makes a chat application that run on the same server with the same domains and I don't want that.. I want in two different servers

Comment: and how I could connect from the client side which is example.com?

Comment: Can you please write me a very small example in the server side and the client side? It will really help me